# Book about children who are trained in a lab for the future

Tags: story-identification

Things I remember about this book (and it's not much):

- Dystopian or Utopian future (I believe it was Dystopian)
- Children where either born in a lab or brought to a lab and
  trained for specific functions in life (Scientist, Janitor, Teachers, Etc.).
- I do remember that there were a few scenes that specific children were trained for specific phobias. Example: The children were in a room and when the color yellow was displayed, a piercing noise blasted them which eventually invoked fear of that color.
- I read the book either early 90's or late 80's. I have a feeling it was early 90's.

I know it's not much to go on, and I'm digging deep in my sponge to remember more. Unfortunately I don't remember the main plot of the story. The scene of the children in the lab is what I remember from long ago.

Comment: Brave New World?

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here.Could you take a look at this [guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/62201) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details that you can remember? Every little bit helps us.

Comment: @Valorum reading the plot of Brave New World, non of that is jogging my memory but some of it is. So, that might be it.

Comment: @amflare I'm trying :) I know it's not much to go on

Comment: @Valorum Yep, this is it. If you post it as the answer, I'll accept it :) Thanks for the quick response

Comment: Is the yellow colour, significant - there are some books set after the coming of The King In Yellow (as per Robert W Chambers, and later Lovecraftian writers)? Are the children being trained to flee Him?  - Oops just seen, it' answered - ignore this.

Comment: @Jenayah how is mine a duplicate when that question was asked almost 2 years after mine?

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker it's about two policies: [dupe-closing story-id when both are accepted](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7067/98028), and [keeping the better question and answer to be left open, regardless of age](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4744/98028). In this case I think the questions are of equivalent quality, but the answer on the dupe includes quotes from the book, which is better for remembering the story than the short summary provided below. (NB: the answer on the dupe is mine, but I'd have voted to close this way even if it wasn't)

Comment: @Jenayah Okay, thank you for the explanation. It makes sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Brave New World](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brave_New_World) by Aldous Huxley.

> The novel opens in the World State city of London in AF 632 (AD 2540 in the Gregorian calendar), where citizens are engineered through artificial wombs and childhood indoctrination programs into predetermined classes (or castes) based on intelligence and labour. Lenina Crowne, a hatchery worker, is popular and sexually desirable, but Bernard Marx, a psychologist, is not. He is shorter in stature than the average member of his high caste, which gives him an inferiority complex